# How to read filenames 10 at a time, process them, then read the next 10?

Tags: perl, filesystems, filenames, readdir

In Perl, how do I read filenames in a directory into a Perl array only 10 at a time?
All directory reading solutions I have found seem only to read the entire list of files into an array at once, but I don't want to read all files at once because there may be millions and I want to keep the memory footprint down.

Answer (score 2):

From the [readdir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) perldoc page you see that readdir return a single directory entry when in scalar context:

> readdir DIRHANDLE
>
> Returns the next directory entry for a directory
>   opened by opendir. If used in list context, returns all the rest of
>   the entries in the directory. If there are no more entries, returns
>   the undefined value in scalar context and the empty list in list
>   context.

Sample code from the same page:

```
opendir(my $dh, $some_dir) || die "Can't open $some_dir: $!";
while (readdir $dh) {
    print "$some_dir/$_\n";
}
closedir $dh;
```

Please note that this is sample code and in a real script you could probably be better served explicitly declaring a variable for the directory returned by readdir and not using the $_ special variable.

Comment: Thank you @Bruno Ramos. So, does the while loop only read the filenames one at a time?

Answer (score 2):

`opendir` is used to read the directory file by file. Then it's just a question of buffering the results until you get the right number.

```
my $dir_qfn = "...";

my @buf;
opendir(my $dh, $dir_qfn)
   or die("Can't open directory \"$qfn\": $!\n");

while (defined( my $fn = readdir($dh) )) {
   my $qfn = "$dir_qfn/$fn";
   push @buf, $qfn;
   process_files(splice(@buf)) if @buf == 10;
}

process_files(@buf) if @buf;
```

`process_file(splice(@buf));` is just short for `process_file(@buf); @buf = ();`

---

That's the straightfoward way of writing it, but what if you wanted to eliminate the duplicated sub call?

```
my $dir_qfn = "...";

my @buf;
opendir(my $dh, $dir_qfn)
   or die("Can't open directory \"$qfn\": $!\n");

while (1) {
   my $fn = readdir($dh);
   if (defined($fn)) {
      my $qfn = "$dir_qfn/$fn";
      push @buf, $qfn;
   }

   if (!defined($fn) || @buf == 10) {
      process_files(splice(@buf));
   }

   last if !defined($fn);
}
```

This allows you to inline `process_file`. For example, if you had

```
sub process_files {
   print("$_\n") for @_;
}
```

you can now replace

```
if (!defined($fn) || @buf == 10) {
   process_files(splice(@buf));
}
```

with

```
if (!defined($fn) || @buf == 10) {
   print("$_\n") for splice(@buf);
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you @ikegami. I'm honoured you answered :)